# Free, minimal nodeJS hosting solution that doesn't require a credit card

Tags: gratis, web-development, node.js, hosted

So I've made a small Discord bot for a small Discord server, which runs with nodeJS. Right now the bot is running on my computer, which means I have to go to the CLI to start it, and which also means the bot is offline if my computer is.

I'm looking for a website that lets me host the bot so it runs 24/7, for free.

As I said this is a really small bot, whose size with dependencies is under 2Mo. Therefore, I need very few storage space and I'm confident there is plenty of freemium hosting services out there that have a free plan that will suit my needs. The bot will also generate very few traffic as I'm pretty sure  the said server will never be over 100 members and the bot is not a vital part of using this server - it just serves some automation and fun purposes.

I heard you can host Discord bots on [Cloud9](https://c9.io/), but in order to create an account on this hosting service, even for the free plan, you need to enter your credit card informations. Not that I think Cloud9 is a scam, but I'd prefer not to put those infos on a website where I know I'll never make any payment and of which I have no idea about the level of security.

I also heard about [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), but this one is apparently just the same : you have to give your credit card info for the bot running 24/7.

Now I'm not a pro developer, I know a thing or two but globally everything backend is very blurry in my mind. That's why I'd like the simplest, most straightforward service possible, but I guess you can't have everything - if it's complicated, i'll find tutorials on how to use it and figure it out somehow. That's also why I come here to ask, because the services I found that *seem* to be what I'm looking for speak most of the time in a slang I can't understand, and it's always very unclear to me from the homepage if the service actually is, well, something that will let me host a Discord bot...

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not services – so this seems off-topic. For details, you might refer to our Meta post on [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/675/185)

Comment: @Izzy, thanks for the clarification. Do you think there any SE website were it would be on topic ?

Comment: I'm not sure. The general answer is: Check the names that *sound* right, then verify via their `/help/on-topic` page plus via the corresponding Meta site's `scope` tag. There once was a "Website Recommendation" site proposed on A51, but AFAIK it didn't make it (check again to make sure).